# Linhas do DataTable se juntando e ficando espessa

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho um DataTable Bootstrap que é carregado em duas partes: O Header é carregado usando HTML normalmente e as linhas são carregadas via JavaScript. O Problema é que quando as linhas se juntam, criam como se fosse uma linha mais espessa (Só ocorre na linha onde destaquei de vermelho na imagem)... Como eu resolvo isso?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<table id="dtPrincipal" class="table table-striped table-bordered center-header " cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

```
function dataTablePrincipalLoad() {

    $('.dataTables_filter input').attr('placeholder', 'Search...').hide();
    var table = $("#dtPrincipal").DataTable({
        "processing": true, // for show progress bar
        "serverSide": true, // for process server side
        "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
        "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
        //"dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
        "ajax": {
            "url": '/pessoa-situacao-gerenciar/getPessoaSituacao',
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columnDefs": [
            //Estilos Das Colunas
            { className: "align-center", "targets": [0] },
            { className: "align-center", "targets": [2] },

            //Largura das Colunas
            { width: 100, targets: 0 },
            { width: 100, targets: 2 }
        ],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "descricao", "name": "Descricao", "autoWidth": true },
            {  

                 "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                     return '<div class="btn-group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown" role="group"><a class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline" title="Visualizar/Editar" data-modal=""><i class="icon wb-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline" title="Excluir"  data-modal=""><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><div class="btn-group" role="group"><button title="Mais Ações" type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="exampleGroupDrop2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="icon wb-more-vertical" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="exampleGroupDrop2" role="menu"><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-time" aria-hidden="true"></i>Histórico</a></div></div></div>'
                } 
            }

        ],
        "language": {
            "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ".",
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
            "sProcessing": "Processando...",
            "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
            "searchPlaceholder": "Digite algo...",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sNext": "Próximo",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                "sLast": "Último"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Vc diz a aparência da linha, fica com uma linha mais espessa?

Comment: Mano o que acontece eh que esta juntando duas bordas, a border-bottom da primeira tabela com a border-top do segundo elemento. Resumindo, basta remover o border-bottom da tabela de cima que resolve

Comment: Resolvi o problema acrescentando ao meu css: table.dataTable thead th {
    border-bottom: 0;
}

Comment: Obrigado gente :)

Comment: De nada jovem, tmj